# TypeError: an integer is required python

Tags: python, datetime, sys

This is my code:

```
today = datetime.date.today()

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    arg_month = sys.argv[1]
    arg_year = sys.argv[2]
    print arg_month
    print arg_year
    lastMonth = datetime.date(day=1, month=arg_month, year=arg_year)
    first = lastMonth + datetime.timedelta(month=1)
    lastMonth = lastMonth.strftime("%Y%m")
    curMonth = first.strftime("%Y%m")   
else:
    first = datetime.date(day=1, month=today.month, year=today.year)
    lastMonth = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    lastMonth = lastMonth.strftime("%Y%m")
    curMonth=(time.strftime("%Y%m"))
```

This is how I run the code:
python lelan.py 01 2015

the output is:

```
01
2015
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lelan.py", line 22, in <module>
    lastMonth = datetime.date(day=1, month=arg_month, year=arg_year)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

How to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: I think you might need to change the indices you are accessing to 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2. In python counting in lists begins from 0 (being the first element) and so on.

Comment: @adarsh, no sys.argv[0] is the <strike>name</strike> relative path of the script.

Comment: True! Didn't notice that it was sys.argv. You'll just have to cast the variables to be integers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because arguments from `sys.argv` are strings. You need to cast them to integers:

```
arg_month = int(sys.argv[1])
arg_year = int(sys.argv[2])
```

Answer (score 5):

All items gotten from command line arguments are strings; the command line doesn't have any type system, and can't distinguish between strings and anything else. So `arg_month` and `arg_year` are strings. You need to cast them to an `int` explicitly:

```
int(arg_month)
```

You may want to consider using the [ArgumentParser](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html) instead, which can simplify this for you:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('month', type=int)
...
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.month)
```